# How to normalize JSON Data correctly Using Pandas - Python

Tags: python, pandas, normalize

I am New to Python and currently facing a problem while normalizing the Json during in python.

In the Example given below , I had found the solution for the nested tag having single values like

{u'c': u'119.743',
      u'h': u'119.891',
      u'l': u'119.249',
      u'o': u'119.341'},

Now we have multiple values in the nested tag so I want the values to be displayed as 3 seperate records with other having same values. Please help.

{u'c': u'119.743',
  u'h': u'119.891',
  u'l': u'119.249',
  u'o': u'119.341'},

{u'c': u'119.743',
  u'h': u'119.891',
  u'l': u'119.249',
  u'o': u'119.341'}

The complete data is given below.

```
The data is given below.
[{u'complete': True,
u'mid': {u'c': u'119.743',
  u'h': u'119.891',
  u'l': u'119.249',
  u'o': u'119.341'},

   {u'c': u'119.743',
  u'h': u'119.891',
  u'l': u'119.249',
  u'o': u'119.341'},

{u'c': u'119.743',
  u'h': u'119.891',
  u'l': u'119.249',
  u'o': u'119.341'},
u'time': u'1488319200.000000000',
u'volume': 14651},

{u'complete': True,
u'mid': {u'c': u'119.893',
  u'h': u'119.954',
  u'l': u'119.552',
  u'o': u'119.738'},
  {u'c': u'119.893',
  u'h': u'119.954',
  u'l': u'119.552',
  u'o': u'119.738'},
  {u'c': u'119.893',
  u'h': u'119.954',
  u'l': u'119.552',
  u'o': u'119.738'},
u'time': u'1488348000.000000000',
u'volume': 10738},

{u'complete': True,
u'mid': {u'c': u'119.946',
  u'h': u'120.221',
  u'l': u'119.840',
  u'o': u'119.888'},
  {u'c': u'119.946',
  u'h': u'120.221',
  u'l': u'119.840',
  u'o': u'119.888'},
  {u'c': u'119.946',
  u'h': u'120.221',
  u'l': u'119.840',
  u'o': u'119.888'},
u'time': u'1488376800.000000000',
u'volume': 10041}]
```